# Is it possible to acces to props of derived classes in a list a base class

Tags: c#, class, oop

I'm new to c# and trying to learn it.

I'm made this following code :

BASE CLASS :

```
namespace Computer
{
    class Component
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public Component()
        {

        }

        public Component(string name, string brand, string model, string category, decimal price)
        {
            Name = name;
            Brand = brand;
            Model = model;
            Category = category;
            Price = price;
        }
    }
}
```

DERIVED CLASS

```
namespace Computer
{
    class Processor : Component
    {
        public double Frequency { get; set; }

        public Processor(string name, string brand, string model, string category, decimal price, double frequency) 
            : base(name, brand, model, category, price)
        {
            Frequency = frequency;
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN PROGRAM :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Computer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var computer = new Computer();

            computer.ItemsList = new List<Component>
            {
                new Component("ASUS ROG Maximus XI Hero Z390", "Asus", "Maximus XI Hero (Wi-Fi)", "Motherboards", 399.99m),
                new Processor("i9-9900k", "Intel", "BX80684I99900K", "Processors", 649.99m, 5.50),
            };

            foreach (var part in computer.ItemsList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Component Description : ");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"Name : {part.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Brand : {part.Brand}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Model : {part.Model}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Category : {part.Category}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Price : ${part.Price}");
                ***Console.WriteLine(part.Frequency);***
                Console.WriteLine("---\n");               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the base class doesn't have the Frequency prop, but is there a way to access to this prop for my new Processor instance? Or maybe I'm doing it badly?

Thank you for your advices!!

Comment: If your base class needs to access properties that are declared in your derived class, it's a sure sign the classes weren't designed properly. However, you don't seem to want to do that, your question is misworded. You want to access the frequency from an entirely different class. In this case, you can look into the is operator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

Comment: You're going to have to cast to `Processor` i.e. `(part as Processor)?.Frequency`

Comment: You might want to add a method to `Component` to create that output string and the override it in `Processor` to include Frequency.

Comment: I think the most clean solution is to add a virtual method in the Component class to get the strings to log and override it in the Processor class (call base and add frequency)